# Как перезапустить AsyncTeleBot после ошибки Aiohttp ClientError: ServerDisconnectedError

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, asyncio

Есть чат-бот, написанный с помощью pyTelegramBotApi и asyncio. При запуске использую такую простую конструкцию:

```
from telebot.async_telebot import AsyncTeleBot
import asyncio

TOKEN = "some token"
bot = AsyncTeleBot(TOKEN, parse_mode=None)
   
# some handlers

async def bot_start():
    await bot.polling(non_stop=True)
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(bot_start())
```

Всё стабильно работает приблизительно от 2 до 5 дней. Однако после возникает ошибка:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "Aiohttp ClientError: ServerDisconnectedError"
ERROR - TeleBot: "Request timeout. Request: method=get url=getUpdates params=<aiohttp.formdata.FormData object at 0x>
```

Пытался обрабатывать ошибку и добавлять запуск в блок while, но особого успеха нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ оказался максимально прост.

Ввёл параметр request_timeout для метода polling и ошибки не возникало уже целый месяц.

`await bot.polling(non_stop=True, request_timeout=90)`